# Apache mod-headers - keep only specific cookies

Tags: regex, apache, cookies, mod-headers

I am trying to use a "RequestHeader edit" directive to manipulate the "Cookie" header and only keep a specific set of cookies from that header.

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie "PATTERN TO REMOVE ALL COOKIES DESPITE OF .." ""
```

Incoming

```
someCookie=someValue; anotherCookie=yada61; cookieToKeep-1=myValue; cookieToKeep-2=myValue2; lastCookie=yada1
```

To keep

```
cookieToKeep-1=myValue; cookieToKeep-2=myValue2;
```

Goal is to remove all cookies but any cookie that starts with "cookieToKeep-".

I found that Pattern `(CookieToKeep-\d=(([\w]*;)|[^\s]+))` gives me all matches for the cookies I need, but I need the negative of this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try negative lookahead (for each cookie name): `^(?!cookieToKeep-).*`.